# How to draw a circle in a double y axis graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib. I am trying to draw an empty circle to specify the data points in a double y axis graph. I used the plt.Cirle to do the work. But it did not work. Could you kindly help me? Here is the code, and what I have got is a rectangle instead of a circle.

```
from matplotlib.patches import *


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.gca()
markers,stems,base = ax1.stem(x1,oscillator,linefmt='k-',markerfmt='ko')
for stem in stems:
    stem.set_linewidth(1)
ax1.set_ylim(0,0.4)
ax1.set_xlim(250,500)
ax1.set_xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Oscillator strength')
ax1.annotate('Oscillator strength', xy=(307,0.31), xytext=(325,0.35),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle= '-|>',connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.5',lw = 1, color ='k'))
circ = plt.Circle((300,0.3), radius=20, edgecolor='g')
ax1.add_artist(circ)


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x2,absorbance,'r-',linewidth=1)
ax2.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax2.set_ylabel('Absorbance',color='r')
ax2.annotate('', xy=(414,0.31), xytext=(450,0.33),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle= '-|>',connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.5',lw = 1, color ='r'))
ax2.text(450,0.33,'Absorbance',color='red')

plt.show()
```

Here is the graph, the blue rectangle should be a circle:

[image: Here is the graph, the blue rectangle should be a circle]

Comment: "It didn't work" is *never* a sufficient problem description. Show the code (see [mcve]) and the problem it produces. Clearly state what you want to achieve. Spend more than 2 sentences on explaining the problem (see [ask]).

Comment: Since this question is now closed, it cannot have an answer until it will be reopened. One option you have is to delete this question and ask a new one which has a [mcve] in it. Note that the above code is not a [mcve], because it cannot be run and tested due to missing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a circle in an axes of very unequal data limits. While the x axis ranges in the ranges of hundreds, the y axis ranges in the range below 1. What you observe as rectangle is hence a very distorted circle.

[image]

For such cases, where the limits are significantly different, or in any case where you want to have a true Circle on screen, the circle should rather be defined in axes coordinates or even better, in display coordinates.

An easy method to produce a circle in display coordinates is a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(303,320,3)
y = np.array([.25,.13,.09,.33,.16,.11])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stem(x,y,linefmt='k-',markerfmt='ko')

ax.scatter([x[3]],[y[3]], s=40**2, edgecolor="green", facecolor="None", linewidth=3 )
ax.axis([250,500,0,.4])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This should solve your problem:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/patch_collection.html

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patches = []

circle = Circle((0.5, 0.8), 0.25) #Filled circle
patches.append(circle)

patches += [
Wedge((.3, .7), .1, 0, 360),             # Full circle
Wedge((.7, .8), .2, 0, 360, width=0.05),  # Full ring
Wedge((.8, .3), .2, 0, 45),              # Full sector
Wedge((.8, .3), .2, 45, 90, width=0.10)] # Ring sector

p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Dear Joe, thank you for your help. I have uploaded the code. But I cannot get a circle from the code.

Comment: Please update your example. `x1` is missing as well as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`